# DynamicModule: results do not update upon the change of input parameters

Tags: dynamic

```
DynamicModule[{FlowratePARK = 100,TemperaturePARK = 350,heatPARKsensible,heatbalance}, 
  heatPARKsensible = 
 ThermodynamicData["Air", 
"Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> 
  Quantity[TemperaturePARK, "DegreesCelsiuss"], 
 "Pressure" -> Quantity[101325, "Pascals"]}]*Quantity[FlowratePARK,"kg"]/Quantity[1,"hour"];
heatbalance = {{Button["Primary Air", 
  CreateDialog[
   Column[{Row[{Style["Flow rate(kg/hr)", Bold, 14], 
       InputField[Dynamic[FlowratePARK]]}], 
     Row[{Style["Flow temperature(\[Degree]C)", Bold, 14], 
       InputField[Dynamic[TemperaturePARK]]}]}]]] -> 
   "Rotary Kiln", 
   Mouseover[Style["Heat Flow", Bold, 12, Orange], 
 Dynamic[heatPARKsensible]]}};
Panel[Dynamic@
LayeredGraphPlot[heatbalance, VertexLabeling -> True, 
ImageSize -> Small]]]
```

Here is the simplified version of code to illustrate a process of heat flow. Here, I made a window by clicking the button to ask for value, then I would like to apply these values to the calculation. I did add `Dynamic` to the value of heat flow, but the value did not change upon the change of `InputField`. So, could anyone tell why it is not working?

Comment: `heatPARKsensible = ThermodynamicData...` is evaluated once, when you are creating Panel for initial values. Add a button to recalculate this, or something which will do what you want to be done.

Comment: @Kuba, in fact i chose to use the dynamic module to take advantage of the interactivity, if i add another button to recalculate, i loss the interactivity or the advantage of dynamicmodule, no? Thx very much for ur response. =)

Comment: I have not idea what do you mean but let me answer the question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say that you want to recalculate `heatPARKsensible` or define it with `SetDelayed` so `Dynamic` can take care of it:

```
DynamicModule[{FlowratePARK = 100, TemperaturePARK = 350, 
  heatPARKsensible, heatbalance}
 ,
 heatbalance = {{
   Button["Primary Air", 
      CreateDialog[
       Column[{Row[{Style["Flow rate(kg/hr)", Bold, 14], 
           InputField[Dynamic[FlowratePARK]]}], 
         Row[{Style["Flow temperature(\[Degree]C)", Bold, 14], 
           InputField[Dynamic[TemperaturePARK]]}]}]], 
       Method -> "Queued"
   ] -> "Rotary Kiln"
   , 
   Mouseover[
     Style["Heat Flow", Bold, 12, Orange], 
     Dynamic[ heatPARKsensible[] ]
 ]}};

 Panel[
  LayeredGraphPlot[heatbalance, VertexLabeling -> True, 
   ImageSize -> Small]]
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   heatPARKsensible[] := 
    ThermodynamicData["Air", 
      "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> 
        Quantity[TemperaturePARK, "DegreesCelsiuss"], 
       "Pressure" -> Quantity[101325, "Pascals"]}]*
     Quantity[FlowratePARK, "kg"]/Quantity[1, "hour"]
   )]
```

You may also want to add `ContinuousAction->True` to your `InputFields`.

Comment: Thx very much for your response, could you explain the meaning of the Print[1] in button. Thx =)

Comment: @Aha sorry, just a left over. is everything else ok?

Comment: Thanks for you solution, it works well, I just want to know why the problem appears, so that I can avoid it for the next time. Thanks very much for your patience.